# Error while loading a translation provider using Multilingual App Toolkit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, multilingual-app-toolkit

Context :
I am trying to use MAT 4.0 on VS 2015 to translate some forms.

Problem :
I have installed both of the extension and the editor and have enabled the selection.
I have mentioned my Neutral language on the Assembly Information dialog box, but when I Right-click the project node in Solution Explorer then Multilingual App Toolkit to add the translation languages I am having a warning box saying that there is a problem with the translation provider manager.
same thing when I try to generate machine translations I'm having :

> An error was encountered while loading a translation provider. While other providers will continue to work, this provider will not be used for generating translations until the issue is resolved.

Can anyone enlighten me on that please ?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I've got the same problem.

Comment: Same problem on VS2022 and MAT 4.2.1.  Used to work, Azure translation endpoint key acquired, updated, still fails.  Not sure but VS2022 Pro, v17.4.4 doesn't show that translation key has been supplied between reboots (maybe a sign?).  But within a session VS holds the key and *still* doesn't translate.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the default translation providers.
One of them requires an Azure subscription and without it raises this error. It can be ignored if you don't use the translation providers.

https://multilingualapptoolkit.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1167898

Comment: That link is now dead.  I am also having this problem.  Can you expand on your answer?